# Dynamically fit DIV Height to Content of another DIV?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        <article id="1">
            <div class="article-header">
                <h2>This is a Header!</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="article-text">
                <p>This is a Text!</p>
            </div>
        </article>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        <article id="2">
            <div class="article-header">
                <h2>This is a much longer Header which will wrap over two lines!</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="article-text">
                <p>This is a much longer Text which will wrap over also two lines!</p>
            </div>
        </article>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.article-header,
.article-text{
    width: 100%;
}
```

For the sake of this Example i filled in Content but actually the content is generated in PHP, means they are created many rows with cols inside.

My Problem right now is that i want to have all containers inside the ROW fit to each other in height. Here is an exampleimage of what i mean:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that html matches your output?

Comment: can you declare min-height?

Comment: You could force the `articel-header`s inside an `article` element to have the same hight using `inline-block` but having the same height in different parents, with dynamic content, that's just won't work with only CSS. Luckily you added the `javascript` tag.

Comment: @Nelson Tan
No that wont work because what will happened if the content is longer then the min height? Then i do have the same problem again ...

Comment: @Andrei V
Thanks for youe help. Yeah i was guessing that CSS just wont cut it, this is why i added Javascript as a possible solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

Using `each` we can fix height of the `div's` dynamically.

```js
var largest = 0; //start with 0

$("article > div").each(function(){ //loop through each section
   var findHeight = $(this).height(); //find the height
   if(findHeight > largest){ //see if this height is greater than "largest" height
      largest = findHeight; //if it is greater, set largest height to this one 
   }  
});

$("article > div").css({"height":largest+"px"});
```

```css
.article-header,
.article-text{
    width: 50%; float:left
}
article > div h2{margin:0px}
article > div {border:1px solid #000}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-12">
        <article id="1">
            <div class="article-header">
                <h2>This is a Header!</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="article-text">
                <p>This is a Text!</p>
            </div>
        </article>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-12">
        <article id="2">
            <div class="article-header">
                <h2>This is a much longer Header which will wrap over two lines!</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="article-text">
                <p>This is a much longer Text which will wrap over also two lines!</p>
            </div>
        </article>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `display:inline-table` and `display:table-cell` 
see this sample fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/p6jg104L/